# What is cLongFixedRectangle?

Tags: c, constants, compile-time-constant, undocumented-behavior

[Everywhere that I found online](https://www.google.com/search?q="cLongFixedRectangle") is just a raw definition like this:

```c
  cLongFixedRectangle           = 'lfrc', /*  0x6c667263  */
```

But nowhere do I see it documented or used. All I could figure out is that it seems to be defined mostly in Apple OSs and IBM OS/2 source code. What is this mysterious constant used for?